# Error deploying more than one stream with a router 1.3.0

Tags: spring-xd

I am encountering the following issue on the 1.3.0 release:

xd:>stream create test1 --definition 'http | router --script="file:/tmp/file1.groovy"' --deploy

this deployes fine.

xd:>stream create test2 --definition 'http --port=9999 | router --script="file:/tmp/file2.groovy"' --deploy

Here is the log trace for the second stream:

> 2015-11-20T16:57:45-0800 1.3.0.RELEASE ERROR
>   DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener -
>   Exception deploying module
>   org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable
>   to register MBean
>   [org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0] with key
>   'org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0'; nested
>   exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException:
>   org.springframework.integration.router:name=org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0,type=MethodInvokingRouter
>     at
>   org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:432)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:792)
>   ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:835)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
>   ~[spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:213)
>   ~[spring-xd-module-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.doDeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:217)
>   ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:200)
>   ~[spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployModule(DeploymentListener.java:365)
>   [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployStreamModule(DeploymentListener.java:334)
>   [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.onChildAdded(DeploymentListener.java:181)
>   [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.childEvent(DeploymentListener.java:149)
>   [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509)
>   [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503)
>   [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92)
>   [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]  at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
>   [guava-16.0.1.jar:na]     at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83)
>   [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500)
>   [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35)
>   [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]    at
>   org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762)
>   [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [na:1.8.0_45]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_45]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [na:1.8.0_45]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_45]
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_45]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_45]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
>   Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException:
>   org.springframework.integration.router:name=org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0,type=MethodInvokingRouter
>     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]    at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]    at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]    at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]    at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]    at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]    at
>   org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:195)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:678)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:615)
>   ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]     ... 30 common
>   frames omitted 2015-11-20T16:57:45-0800 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO
>   DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener - Path
>   cache event:
>   path=/deployments/modules/allocated/e38af683-03a1-4f46-abd9-abccb8aae1f3/test2.sink.router.1,
>   type=CHILD_REMOVED 2015-11-20T16:57:45-0800 1.3.0.RELEASE INFO
>   DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener -
>   Undeploying module [ModuleDescriptor@56110771 moduleName = 'router',
>   moduleLabel = 'router', group = 'test2', sourceChannelName = [null],
>   sinkChannelName = [null], index = 1, type = sink, parameters =
>   map['script' ->
>   'file:/tmp/dirt/att-example/groovy/transfer.router.cps.groovy'],
>   children = list[[empty]]]

Comment: I did attempt to add a label to the router module but to no available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug - <strike>please open a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD).</strike> [JIRA Issue here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3709).

<strike>I haven't come up with a work-around (so far), aside from disabling JMX.</strike>

For some reason, the main spring MBean exporter is trying to export the router; normally, the `IntegrationMBeanExporter` disables that (when present).

**EDIT**

Here's a work-around...

Create this file and put it under `xd/config` as

`xd/config/META-INF/spring-xd/plugins/jmx/mbean-exporters.xml` ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int-jmx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx/spring-integration-jmx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:mbean-export default-domain="xd.${xd.stream.name:${xd.job.name:}}" />

    <int-jmx:mbean-export object-naming-strategy="moduleObjectNamingStrategy" />

    <!-- TODO: Add BatchMbeanExporter -->
    <util:properties id="objectNameProperties">
        <prop key="group">${xd.group.name}</prop>
        <prop key="label">${xd.module.label}</prop>
        <prop key="type">${xd.module.type}</prop>
        <prop key="sequence">${xd.module.sequence}</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <bean id="moduleObjectNamingStrategy"
        class="org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.jmx.ModuleObjectNamingStrategy">
        <constructor-arg name="domain" value="xd.${xd.stream.name:${xd.job.name:}}" />
        <constructor-arg name="objectNameProperties" ref="objectNameProperties" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This replaces the standard file and makes the stream name part of the MBean domain so the MBean names are unique. The only difference to the standard file is the addition of the `default-domain` to the context mbean exporter.

We still need to address the underlying issue as to why the normal exporter does not have that bean suppressed, but this should get you going.

Comment: Gary - you are a life saver! Thank you! We are about to go into our app's testing/check out phase next week and I really wanted to make this transition to 1.3.0 before that window closes. I was just about to sit down to write another sink to do this simple routing - you saved me hours i don't have to spare at the moment  - thanks!