# Exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: xd.batchMessageDispatcherStream

Tags: spring-xd

I am getting below exception when xd tries to deploy the  stream its coming from http-client of xd  .I get this error many time with other modules too including my custom modules.Not able to get root cause.Some time redeployment works.3 container 1 admin 1 zookeeper .
My server.yml has this

```
XD_JMX_ENABLED: true
endpoints:
  jolokia:
    enabled: ${XD_JMX_ENABLED:true}
  jmx:
    enabled: ${XD_JMX_ENABLED:true}
    uniqueNames: true

2016-04-09T16:11:02-0400 1.2.1.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ModuleRedeployer - Deployment state for stream 'batchMessageDispatcherStream': DeploymentStatus{state=incomplete,error(s)=org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter#0#5a327686-08b8-4330-ab11-f5b9721d1b54'; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [MessageChannelMonitor: [name=input, sends=0]] with key 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=input'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: xd.batchMessageDispatcherStream:module=batchMessageDispatcherStream.processor.http-client.3,component=MessageChannel,name=input
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176)
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
            at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:770)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
            at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139)
            at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:213)
            at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.doDeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:217)
            at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:200)
            at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployModule(DeploymentListener.java:365)
            at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployStreamModule(DeploymentListener.java:334)
            at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.onChildAdded(DeploymentListener.java:181)
            at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.childEvent(DeploymentListener.java:149)
            at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509)
            at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503)
            at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92)
            at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297)
            at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83)
            at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500)
            at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35)
            at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [MessageChannelMonitor: [name=input, sends=0]] with key 'org.springframework.integration:type=MessageChannel,name=input'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: xd.batchMessageDispatcherStream:module=batchMessageDispatcherStream.processor.http-client.3,component=MessageChannel,name=input
            at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625)
            at org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter.registerChannels(IntegrationMBeanExporter.java:783)
            at org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter.doStart(IntegrationMBeanExporter.java:452)
```

Comment: What version of Spring XD? A similar issue was fixed in 1.3.1.

Comment: We are using 1.2.1.I see this in different inbuilt modules and xd modulesThis issues happened with http-client

Comment: [This workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838502/error-deploying-more-than-one-stream-with-a-router-1-3-0/33845601#33845601) might work for you, but I suggest you try with 1.3.1.

Comment: Thanks Gary.We are upgrading to 1.3.1 next month.