# Spring XD - Could not resolve placeholder 'xd.module.sequence'

Tags: spring-xd

I am dealing with an issue similar to the following posts:

[Spring -XD Stream deployment failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439296/spring-xd-stream-deployment-failure)

[issue in spring xd cluster when deploying my module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514393/issue-in-spring-xd-cluster-when-deploying-my-module)

Also, saw that a JIRA ticket was opened:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/XD-3727

I created a basic stream with a custom transformer module: `stream create test-stream --definition "file | enricher | log" --deploy`
Locally, when running singlenode, my jar uploads and the stream is successfully created. However, when running in distributed mode, the stream fails on:

```
2017-02-20T22:40:11+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE WARN 61699 DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'objectNameProperties' defined in null: Could not resolve placeholder 'xd.module.sequence' in string value "${xd.module.sequence}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'xd.module.sequence' in string value "${xd.module.sequence}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:222) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:86) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:284) ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:166) ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:674) ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519) ~[spring-context-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:139) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.module.core.SimpleModule.initialize(SimpleModule.java:213) [spring-xd-module-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.doDeploy(ModuleDeployer.java:217) [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.module.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:200) [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployModule(DeploymentListener.java:365) [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.deployStreamModule(DeploymentListener.java:334) [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.onChildAdded(DeploymentListener.java:181) [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.xd.dirt.server.container.DeploymentListener.childEvent(DeploymentListener.java:149) [spring-xd-dirt-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:509) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$5.apply(PathChildrenCache.java:503) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer$1.run(ListenerContainer.java:92) [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:297) [guava-16.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.listen.ListenerContainer.forEach(ListenerContainer.java:83) [curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache.callListeners(PathChildrenCache.java:500) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.EventOperation.invoke(EventOperation.java:35) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.curator.framework.recipes.cache.PathChildrenCache$10.run(PathChildrenCache.java:762) [curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'xd.module.sequence' in string value "${xd.module.sequence}"
           at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
           at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer$PlaceholderResolvingStringValueResolver.resolveStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:258) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveStringValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:282) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:204) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitMap(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:262) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.resolveValue(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:198) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitPropertyValues(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:141) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinitionVisitor.visitBeanDefinition(BeanDefinitionVisitor.java:82) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
           at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.2.2.RELEASE.jar:4.2.2.RELEASE]
           ... 31 common frames omitted
```

In the logs, I am seeing this:

```
2017-02-20T16:02:52+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE DEBUG 25853 DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [zk-properties]
2017-02-20T16:02:52+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE DEBUG 25853 DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [commandLineArgs]
2017-02-20T16:02:52+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE DEBUG 25853 DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [systemProperties]
2017-02-20T16:02:52+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE DEBUG 25853 DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [systemEnvironment]
2017-02-20T16:02:52+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE DEBUG 25853 DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [random]
2017-02-20T16:02:52+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE DEBUG 25853 DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]#container]
2017-02-20T16:02:52+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE DEBUG 25853 DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [applicationConfig: [file:/opt/pivotal/spring-xd-1.3.0.RELEASE/xd/config//servers.yml]]
2017-02-20T16:02:52+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE DEBUG 25853 DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [applicationConfig: [file:./config/servers.yml]]
2017-02-20T16:02:52+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE DEBUG 25853 DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]]
2017-02-20T16:02:52+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE DEBUG 25853 DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/servers.yml]]
2017-02-20T16:02:52+0000 1.3.0.RELEASE DEBUG 25853 DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Could not find key 'spring.profiles.default' in any property source. Returning [null]
```

I tried setting `xd.module.sequence` = `default` in application.yml which is on my classpath in my module since the logs show: `Searching for key 'spring.profiles.default' in [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.yml]]`. However, the same exception was thrown. Could anyone provide insight into how to get around this issue?

Comment: Oh, I see you referenced that JIRA - this is simply weird; there is clearly something wrong with the container. I fear you will need to run a debugger on that container to find out why the plugin is not populating the property. We've never been able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: What version of XD are you using?

Comment: This is version 1.3.0.RELEASE

Comment: I just removed an import in my application context which defines a jpa repository and the stream deployed successfully. so, somehow this import seems to be causing this

Comment: The properties registered by each plugin are loaded into a property source. Do you see anything like these for the `xd.module.sequence`? `Searching for key 'initialDelay' in [properties-2]
Searching for key 'initialDelay' in [properties-1]
Searching for key 'initialDelay' in [properties-0]` Each property source registered by a plugin gets a name `properties-n`.

Comment: I see this log for `initialDelay`, but not for `xd.module.sequence`

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround at best, but, if you don't need Spring Integration MBeans, you can replace the `mbean-exporters.xml` with one that does not have the `<int-jmx:mbean-exporter/>` and related beans.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838502/error-deploying-more-than-one-stream-with-a-router-1-3-0/33845601#33845601) shows how to replace that configuration file with a custom one.

Or you can disable JMX altogether in `servers.yml`.

If you do need the MBeans, you'd have to come up with unique values for the `sequence` property. Perhaps an incrementing `AtomicInteger` `<bean/>`.